# iOS - Keeping Track Of An Object Instance Using KVO

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing

Is it possible to keep track of the instance of an object to check whether it is allocated and initialised or set to nil?

I declared the object in .h file and also tried in .m file.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) TestObject *testObj;

@end
```

Then I tried this but didn't work.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"testObj" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];

    _testObj = [[TestObject alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: see this [Key-Value Observing](http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/)

Comment: If you use the property setter instead of accessing the backing variable directly, it should work (assuming I've guessed right about your definition of "work").  (i.e. `self.testObj = [[TestObject alloc] init];`)

Comment: @PhillipMills Thank you!. I just used the property setter and that worked! When I assign the value directly to nil, the callback wasn't called. Now it is working with the setter. Thanks again.

Comment: @WarifAkhandRishi Thank you for the link. I will read it to gain more understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to got it work by using the property setter.

So, instead of:

```
_testObj = [[TestObject alloc] init];
```

I did it like:

```
self.testObj = [[TestObject alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(testObj)) options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];

    _testObj = [[TestObject alloc] init];
}
```

Then Observe like this:

```
    -(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context{

        if ([keyPath isEqualToString:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(testObj))]) {
    //PERFORM YOUR OPERATIONS
    }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, but the result is the same as what I did.

Comment: I managed to get it work through the help of Philip Mills by using the property setter. Thank you for the answer.